# JPA same table with two implementing classes

Tags: jpa

I have an entity `Product` which contains another entity `Category`.

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    ...
    private Category category;
}
```

However, mobile products need a special kind of category.

```
public class MobileProduct extends Product implements Serializable {
    ...
    private MobileCategory mobileCategory;
}
```

It makes sense to make `MobileCategory` inherit `Category` because in this case you won't need two classes for products but if you want to create queries using `MobileCategory` attributes, JPA may not allow that. If you choose to have two classes with a inheritance relationship, you are using exactly the same table with exactly the same attributes but with two implementing classes.

Which approach should I choose?

Comment: Are you aware of JPA's support for inheritance strategies and polymorphic queries?

Comment: Hi kistja, I know that there are polymorphic queries in JPA but does it mean I can use properties that only exist in subclasses for queries in superclasses?